# Custom taxonomy rewrite give pagination 404

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, pagination

I have a Custom taxonomy with this rewrite:

```
'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => '/', 'with_front' => false),
```

So every term will look like this:

```
https://example.com/term/
```

the problem with the pagination pages give 404

```
https://example.com/term/page/1/ 404
https://example.com/term/page/2/ 404 etc..
```

If I put a base to the rewrite like this :

```
'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => '/t', 'with_front' => false),
```

The pagination pages works :

```
https://example.com/t/term/page/1/ Results
```

But I want the terms to show without a base.

How can I make the pagination work with the first rewrite?

Comment: I'm not sure you can. `https://example.com/term/page/1/` is going to have WP look for a _page_ rather than a term archive.